# Query Azure filewall data using the Java SDK?

Tags: java, azure, firewall

I'm trying to poll some data about the Firewall using the Java SDK.
I can't figure out how I am supposed to do so.

I went over all the documentation
Tried using similar methods
And I have tried accessing the firewall data through other objects like ApplicationGateways

```java
private Azure azure = null;
...
ApplicationGateways applicationGateways = azure.applicationGateways();
applicationGateways.inner().list();
```

I expect an object that includes data of NAT rule collections, Network rule collections, Application rule collections

And of course, details about each object within those collections

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no available Azure java SDK which can manage Azure Firewall. You can use Azure REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/firewall/) to manage the Firewall resource.

Or, you can use Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI at the moment.